# VS2013 create a new MVC project runs fine, update all packages via NuGet get error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Created a new MVC API project with VS2013, Target Framework 4.5.1.  Compiles and runs fine.  Went to NuGet and updated all the packages and now get the following runtime error.

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A
>   originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location .....

I'm thinking I have to modify this in the web.config

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" 
  type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,
  System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,
  System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,
  System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: Which packages did you add?

Comment: I just created a default project using MVC web api.  Then i updated all the packages.

Comment: Which specific packages?

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't realize that updating via NuGet would upgrade MVC to 5.  After I followed these instructions everything was working.

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)